# How to Generate Histogram Chart

Tags: php, imagemagick, histogram

I have an website where people share photographs . I am generating Photo Histogram value.. I want to design the histogram chart using the value of RGB.

How I can develop chart for histogram?

I am expecting output in the form of chart !

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick("thing.png");
$pixels=$image->getImageHistogram();
foreach($pixels as $p){
 $colors = $p->getColor();
 foreach($colors as $c){
        print( "$c\t" );
 }
 print( "\t:\t" . $p->getColorCount() . "\n" );
}
?>
```

This will print out something like:

```
252    250    252    1    :    125
194    156    182    1    :    126
109    18    79    1    :    11440
2    117    162    1    :    12761
255    255    255    1    :    40769
```

...where the colums are red, green, blue, alpha, followed by the number of times that colour appears in the image.

Comment: what kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: No answers :( any one can help me

Comment: html chart? image chart? also i understand the first 3 numbers of every line is the rgb values of the color and the last number is the times it apears .. what is the 1?